# How to only start network interface when usb-stick is connected?

Tags: networking, wifi, ifconfig

I have a tinkerboard setup, that it start its network configuration on startup, and opens a bridge. Now I need a setup, where the wlan only boots, when i connect an external device. Preferably if a usb stick is connected it should come up, otherwise the wlan should stay disabled. (and the bridge as well). The check should only happen on startup, i do not need a later check.

I thought about adding a line in the pre-up statement of the wlan interface if an usb device is connected, while checking if the directory where it supposed to be exists. But this does not yield any results. See the marked line in the code below.

Any ideas how to solve that issue?

Thanks in advance.

Lennart

```
➜  ~ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d


#### FOR Access Point ####
# localhost
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# wireless interface
allow-hotplug wlan0
#pre-up [-d "/sys/block/sda"]  <-- Here i wanted to check if the usb is connected
iface wlan0 inet manual
iface wlan0 inet6 manual

# ethernet interface 
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth0 inet6 manual

# network bridge with static ip adress
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
pre-up ifup wlan0 eth0
bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
bridge_fd 0
bridge_stp off
address 192.168.1.100
broadcast 192.168.1.255
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of right now would be to create a partition with a readable file system on your usb and update your `/etc/fstab` using the UUID of that partition to always mount it to a specific location:

```
# /etc/fstab
...
UUID=12345678-1234-5678-1234-123456789012 /mnt/trigger_usb ext4 noatime 0 1
...
```

Then create a file on that partition `touch /mnt/trigger_usb/trigger`.

Now the hard part is dependent upon whether you use `systemd` or some sort of RC (OpenRC).

For example, on `systemd` you would have to create a unit file under (might be system dependent) `/etc/systemd/system/conditional_wifi.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Wifi Conditional Startup
DefaultDependencies=no
After=systemd-sysctl.service
Before=sysinit.target
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/your/start/script.sh
ExecReload=/path/to/your/reload/script.sh
ExecStop=/path/to/your/stop/script.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and enable it `systemctl enable conditional_wifi.service`.

Create a `script.sh` which would check the existence of the file

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e /mnt/trigger_usb/trigger ]; then
  # start your wifi here
fi
```

---

Alternative solution to check for an existence of a connected usb device instead of a trigger file

```
#!/bin/bash
usb=$(/dev/disk/by-path/*usb* | grep -v "part" | awk '{print $NF}'| awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' | sort)
if [ -n "$usb" ]; then
  # start your wifi here
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, that does sound though as if i would need a specific usb stick with that UUID then. I would prefer it to be any usb stick, sicne in the end i want to have the image on different boards and they all should be triggerable. Do you have any ideas how to achive that?

Comment: Sure, check on the sole existence of a connected usb like so `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/*usb*  | grep -v "part" | awk '{print $NF}'|  awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' | sort`. Or you could employ `lsusb` and go from there.

Comment: so basically swap the if part of the script.sh to check for a usb. Alright i will try that. Thank you, will let you know if i was successful

Comment: Yes, give it a try and if you need further help, let me know.